# how to "ignore" @JsonIgnore while serializing?

Tags: jackson

I have a String attribute "version" in java class. I am using Jackson object mapper to serialize Java Class Object to JSON.

I am serializing same class for two use cases, 1) to store JSON value to key-value db store, and 2) to send response back to API call.

For first use case I need "version" attribute in serialized JSON and for second use case I don't need it to send back to user.

Using @JsonIgnore to version will not get me that attribute in both use cases.

I searched enough to see that is there any configuration I can set on Jackson mapper to ignore @JsonIgnore in some cases? No luck so far! Thanks for suggestions or workarounds in advance.

Comment: why don't have two different methods to do two different things? and please update code

Comment: @Deadpool Thanks. 
Do you mean having two different logic (Jackson and something else) to serialize? 
If not, using Jackson for same class will always result same, only way I see is to have different classes for both cases (like ResponseData and PersistData).

Comment: Nope you don't need two different classes, here is the way, don't serialize 'null' fields, (you can do this by annotations) and while saving into database set that property to null and it will not serialize it @user3234777

Comment: Wonderful, it is a good suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have multiple representations you can use `@JsonView`.

```
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }

    public static class Private {
    }
}

public class User {
    public int id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public String name;
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: mapper.writerWithView(Views.Private.class), is the trick. Thank you so much @Konstantin

Answer (score 1):

Do it in simple way, while in the second case set `version` to `null` and add this property on class level or property level

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```